# Function assigned to variable return undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I create a function which saves in a variable `text` the content of my clipboard.

I want to return the function output to another variable called `my_text`, however I am not able to do so.
I have to do that since I want to apply some NLP algorithm to `my_text`

I get `my_text is undefined`

```
function paste() {
  navigator.clipboard.readText()
  .then(text => {

    console.log(text);
    return text
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Failed to read clipboard contents: ", err);
  });

}

var my_text = paste()`
```

I think it is because my function `paste()` is async, but I am still not sure how to assign what it returns to a variable.

Comment: Put `my_text = text;` in the `.then()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the function - only the inner functions.

```
return navigator.clipboard.readText().then(...).catch(...);
```

Alternatively, use an `async` function.

```
async function paste() {
  try {
    const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
    console.log(text);
    return text;
  } catch(er) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too but I get: `[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: "undefinied"`. I would like the "text" to be returned.

Comment: If I use the alternative, I get `await is only valid in async function`

Comment: Fixed, try now @Prova12.

Comment: Thanks, now `[[PromiseValue]]:` contains the text I want. I have to find out how to assign it to my variable `my_text` because now it return the promise while I just want to the content of `[[PromiseValue]]:`

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from your paste function. Try this.

```
  function paste() {
    navigator.clipboard
      .readText()
      .then(text => {
        //call another function
        //or simply do the paste operation here
        processTextFurther(text);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error("Failed to read clipboard contents: ", err);
      });
  }

  function processTextFurther(copiedText) {
    console.log(copiedText);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, now `[[PromiseValue]]:` contains the text I want. I have to find out how to assign it to my variable my_text because now it return the promise while I just want to the content of `[[PromiseValue]]:`

Comment: You can assign it in to `processTextFurther` function and then do whatever you want with it.